# Check string for all digits and if any white space using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, textbox

I'm checking a string value using Linq, if it has all digits using the following query:

```
bool isAllDigits = !query.Any(ch => ch < '0' || ch > '9');
```

But if user enters a space, along with digits (eg: `"123 456"`, `"123456 "`) this check fails. Is there a way that I can check for white spaces as well?

I don't want to trim out the white spaces, because I use this text box to search with text, which contains spaces in between.

Comment: Side note: I'd recommend using search engine first (avoid serach on http://www.disney.com for programming question) - use google or yahoo or https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+Check+string+for+all+digits+and+if+any+white+space

Comment: While this is all well and good if you did get any more complex on your validation I would recommend looking into regex expressions for things like phone numbers, credit cards and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool isAllDigits = query.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsDigit(c));
```

These methods are built into the framework and instead of rolling your own checks, I would suggest using these.

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GGxI8a) to demonstrate.

### EDIT

As pointed out in the comments, `char.IsDigit()` will return true for other "digit" characters as well (i.e not *just* '0'-'9', but also other language/culture number representations as well).  The full list (I believe) can be found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).

In addition, `char.IsWhiteSpace()` will also return true for various types of whitespace characters (see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details).

If you want to *only* allow `0-9` and a regular 'ol space character, you can do this:

```
bool isAllDigits = s.All(c => (c < 57 && c > 48) || c == 32);
```

I am using the decimal values of the ASCII characters ([for reference](http://www.asciitable.com/)), but you could also continue doing it the way you are currently:

```
bool isAllDigits = s.All(c => (c < '9' && c > '0') || c == ' ');
```

Either way is fine, the important thing to note is the parentheses.  You want any character that is greater than 0, but less than 9 **OR** just a single space.

Comment: Note that while answer exactly what asked in the question this code accepts significantly wider range of characters than original one by including "٦" and other native digits and large variety of space characters.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I probably spent way too much effort on a post OP could have easily answered with basic google skills. Hopefully they learn _something_ from it (rather than just copy & pasting code).  I addressed your (very valid) concerns in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isAllDigits = !query.Any(ch => (ch < '0' || ch > '9') && ch != ' ');
```

Comment: Posting code only isn't very helpful.  Explain your code/answer.